# Is there a plugin in netbeans or eclipse that can track the active code during project/application run?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, plugins, netbeans-8

I'd like to see what codes are active when I run a java application in Netbeans/eclipse with out using break-point is there such tool?

Comment: you can use log.debug() in each step. There is no such  tool so far i know to view what codes are implementing line by line. I use log.debug() where i need to monitor the functioning.

Comment: The execution will be much faster how would you see the code which is being executed ?? You should use the debugger and if you want to see which part of the code is used then you should go with the code coverage tool.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a code coverage tool? We're using Clover. It will use different color to highlight which part of code is executed in a test. It has a eclipse plugin.

Answer (score -1):

You don't even need a plugin. Just use the `jstack` command, or `kill -QUIT <java pid>` if you are in linux. It will dump you the current stack of all your threads.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html

It might help you check what code is being executed at a point of time. Yes, it just shows you an "snapshot", not a real execution, but it might suffice your requirements (I don't know what they are)